# Django views.py Как прописать фильтр для вывода комментариев к статье

Tags: django, django-filter

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как прописать фильтр для 
context['articleusercomment'] = ArticleUserComment.objects.all(), 
чтобы комментарии выводились для конкретной статьи (сейчас комментарии выводятся для всех статей)

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
article_name = models.CharField("Название статьи", max_length=30, unique=True)
article_url = models.SlugField("URL статьи", max_length=30, unique=True)
article_text = models.CharField("Текст статьи", max_length=5000, blank=True)

class ArticleUserComment(MPTTModel):
"""Отзывы пользователей"""
article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="статья")
user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Имя пользователя", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
comment_text = models.TextField("Комментарий", max_length=5000)
comment_date = models.DateTimeField("Дата", auto_now_add=True)
parent = TreeForeignKey('self', verbose_name="Родительский комментарий", 
            on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='comment_child')
```

views.py

```
class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
model = Article
slug_field = 'article_url'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['articleusercomment'] = ArticleUserComment.objects.all()
    return context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
context['articleusercomment'] = ArticleUserComment.objects.filter(article=self.object)
```

Comment: Cannot resolve keyword 'article_name' into field. Choices are: comment_child, comment_date, comment_moderate, comment_text, article, article_id, id, level, lft, parent, parent_id, rght, tree_id, user_name, user_name_id

По идее надо как-то через article_id делать

Comment: @ArgumentSite там два нижних подчеркивания

Comment: Если два подчеркивания
Related Field got invalid lookup: name

Comment: @ArgumentSite поправил ответ

Comment: Ошибок нет, но ни одного комментария не выводится

Comment: @ArgumentSite может потому что их нет?

Comment: ArticleUserComment.objects.all() ну так-то они есть

Comment: @ArgumentSite ну так то вы выводите все комментарии что есть. А данным запросом выводятся комментарии к определенной статье (по точному совпадению названию статьи)

Comment: Ни в одной статье нет комментариев. Их всего три. Ко всем были написаны тестовые комментарии

Comment: @ArgumentSite вы явно делаете что-то не то. Напишите `print(context['articleusercomment'])` и посмотрите что у вас выводит в консоль при переходе на страницу, для которого описан этот класс

Comment: С вашим вариантом фильтра - <TreeQuerySet []>. С objects.all() - <TreeQuerySet [список комментариев ко всем статьям]>

Comment: @ArgumentSite изменил ответ, попробуйте так